# filter multidimentional arrays with multiple values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filter

I have three multidimensional arrays. I want to filter out values in the first array that match two values in the other two arrays.

Array 1 $a[] contains location $a[LOC], quantity $a[QTY] and last activity date $a[DATE].

---

Array 2 $b[] contains all locations and their last activity date

---

Array 3 $c[] contains all locations and their current quantity

I need to remove from array $a the locations that appear in array $b which have an activity date bigger than that in array $a (for the same location) and remove from array $a the locations with quantities not matching the same location in array $c.

I have tried combinations of foreach loops with array_intersects but cant seem to get anywhere near what I need.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show what you've tried. It should just be an `if()` statement that compares with the corresponding values in the other two arrays. We're not going to write it for you, but we'll help you fix your attempt.

Comment: You don't need `array_intersect`. Just a single `foreach` loop that uses `unset()` when the element meets the criteria to remove it.

Comment: show some example data

Comment: Would I not need two foreach loops with an if statement
`foreach ($a as $key => $val) {
$location = $val['LOC'];
$date = $val['DATE'];`
//this would give me one entry in the first array I would need to compare with each entry in the other two arrays to see if there is a match, no?
could I use array_search to find the same location in array $b
`array_search($location,$b)`
}

Comment: show some sample data and the output you want from that sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this,

```
$b_loc = array_column($b, 'LOC');
$b_date = array_column($b, 'DATE');
$c_loc = array_column($c, 'LOC');
$c_qty = array_column($c, 'QTY');

foreach ($a as $index => $val) {
    $b_pick = array_search($val['LOC'], $b_loc);
    if($b_pick){
        if($val['DATE'] <= $b_date[$b_pick]){
            unset( $a[$index] );
        }
    }
    $key_qty = array_search($val['LOC'], $c_loc);

        if( ($val['QTY']!=$c_qty[$key_qty]) ){
            unset( $a[$index] );
        }   
}
```